# Measuring the spacetime curvature of an object

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, tensor-calculus, curvature

Suppose that I want to measure the amount of curvature of spacetime that an object in space creates, like the star Rigel? How would I proceed to do so? Would I use the Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$ or the Riemann curvature tensor $R^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu\gamma}$? Or would I proceed to use the Einstein field equation?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Do you mean calculate or determine rather than measure?

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $R^a_{bcd}$ give the curvature directly. To measure them there are various methods: e.g. measure the angles of a triangle or the circumference of a circle or the timing of clocks so as to determine geodesic deviation.

Comment: So If I have a Want to calculate the amount of spacetime curvature of the star Rigel using the Riemann curvature tensor, how would I proceed to do so? Just the normal way using the commutator of 2 covariant derivatives acting on a vector?

Comment: @aygx that is one way to obtain $R^a_{bcd}$, but it might not be the easiest. I would consider the geodesic deviation equation.

Comment: @aygx to calculate curvature, use the EFE. The curvature around Rigel can be very well approximated by the Kerr metric, which is an exact solution of the EFE for a rotating source (but it is only valid above the surface of the star).